# Save model with weights using state dict Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a PyTorch model class and its statedict with the weights.
I'd like to save the model directly with its weight in a .pt file using `torch.save(model, PATH)` but that simply saves the state dict again.

How do I save the model with the loaded_weights in it?

What I'm currently doing

```
lin_model = ModelClass(args)
lin_model.load_state_dict(torch.load('state_dict.pt'))
torch.save(lin_model, PATH)
```

I want the newly saved model to be a fully loaded pt file. Please help me here,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the pytorch documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#saving-loading-model-for-inference), when you use `torch.save(model, PATH)` it saves the entire model with the class. But here is the problem. It doesn't work every time. You see, the saved model is in pickle format, but the pickle file does not save the exact directory structure but just a path to the file containing the model class. So this saving method can break in various ways when used in other projects.

Comment: How do I overcome that?

Comment: It sometimes happens, not always! And you have to keep the class to load the checkpoint file. And that's the best practice.